# Microdisplacement skewed image

Tags: shaders, displacement

[image: skewed render]

Hi, I´ve been trying to get a microdisplacement on a plane from a .jpg 8 bit and a 16 bit .png with a resulting skewed image. How do I fix that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check that a displacement node is used before displacement and that your preview and render options allow for 1 pixel detail. Max subdivisions allows your displacement to be further refined at render time.
Don´t forget to add a displacement modifier on simple mode and check adaptive.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that the Blender version is 2.79.4 - presumably a development build - and the Displacement socket is now a Vector rather than a Scalar value. The new Displacement node allows you to generate the displacement vector to mimic the old Displacement socket behaviour.